# Understanding the difference between different C pointer assignment

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

I am trying to understand the difference between two type of pointer assignment.

```
uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
uint8_t* pNextInputBytes = pInputByte;
```

In this case, since pInputByte[byteCount] is an array, does the second line write the address of this array into pNextInputByte? To clarify just calling array variable name without index return its address?

My other question is how would the operation be different if we write it in the following way.

```
uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
uint8_t* pNextInputBytes;
pNextInputBytes = &pInputByte;
```

Comment: The second should get a compiler warning because a `uint8_t *` is very different from a `uint8_t (*)[]`.  The latter is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a value.

Comment: Also array declaration allocates memory for you, and bare pointer requires either allocation or assigning an existing value (that's what you correctly do in your first example).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus in this declaration

```
uint8_t* pNextInputBytes = pInputByte;
```

the array used as an initializer is converted to pointer to its first element and has the type `int *`. This value is assigned to the declared pointer.

In this statement

```
pNextInputBytes = &pInputByte;
```

there is applied the unary operator & for an object of the array type. So the type of the expression `&pInputByte` is `uinmt8_t ( * )[byteCount]`.  But in the left side of the assignment there is an object of the type `uint8_t *`. There is no implicit conversion from the one type to another. So the compiler will issue an error.

Instead you could write

```
uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
uint8_t (*pNextInputBytes )[byteCount];
pNextInputBytes = &pInputByte;
```

To make it more clear introduce a typedef name for the array type

```
typedef uint8_t T[byteCount];
```

Then you can declare the array and a pointer to array the following way

```
T pInputByte;
T *pNextInputBytes = &pInputByte;
```

Now if to substitute the typedef name T in the pointer declaration for the defined type then you will get

```
uint8_t ( *pNextInputBytes )[byteCount] = &pInputByte;
```

To see the difference between two pointers one of which has the type `uint8_t *` and other `uint8_t ( * )[byteCount]` write the following demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t byteCount = 10;
    uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
    uint8_t *pNextInputBytes1 = pInputByte;
    uint8_t ( *pNextInputBytes2 )[byteCount] = &pInputByte;

    printf( "sizeof( *pNextInputBytes1 ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *pNextInputBytes1 ) );
    printf( "sizeof( *pNextInputBytes2 ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *pNextInputBytes2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( *pNextInputBytes1 ) = 1
sizeof( *pNextInputBytes2 ) = 10
```

Pay attention to that the prefix `p` used in the name of the array will confuse readers of the code.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

```
uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
uint8_t* pNextInputBytes = pInputByte;
```

---

> In this case, since `pInputByte[byteCount]` is an array, does the second line write the address of this array into `pNextInputByte`?

Not the address of the array, the address of the first element of the array. But basically you´re right.

> To clarify just calling array variable name without index return its address?

An array when not used with an index element `[i]` decays to a pointer to the first element and returns the address of this first element, except, as user [ex nihilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326670/understanding-the-difference-between-different-c-pointer-assignment/60326900?noredirect=1#comment106718892_60326900) mentioned in the comments, when it is [an operand to sizeof(), the unary `&` operator or is a string literal used to initialize another array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). Citation from ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11).

---

#### 2.

> My other question is how would the operation be different if we write it in the following way:

```
uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
uint8_t* pNextInputBytes;
pNextInputBytes = &pInputByte;
```

The third line is the problem. You need to omit the ampersand operator `&` to get it compiled properly without any warnings:

```
pNextInputBytes = pInputByte;
```

But if you blend out that typo, both codes are equivalent, yes.

---

By the way, You should not precede `pInputByte` with a `p`, when `p` shall stand for "pointer" (I only can speculate).

Comment: "_An array when not used with an index element `[i]` decays to a pointer to the first element. It returns the address of this first element._" -- This is incorrect. [Array expressions decay to pointers to their first elements unless they are operands to `sizeof`, unary `&`, or are string literals used to initialize another array.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) The Standard does not say that there is no array decay when an array is indexed, but does say that [`E1[E2]` is equivalent to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2)

Comment: @exnihilo Thank you for the hint. I´ve take that into an edit.

Answer (score 0):

1. `uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
   uint8_t* pNextInputBytes = pInputByte;`

In this example, we are assigning the address of the array, which is pointing to the first element in the array. For example, when you try to access first element of the array, you can say *pNextInputBytes and for next element *(pNextInputBytes+1) - +1 takes you to the address of the second element in the array.

2. `uint8_t pInputByte[byteCount];
   uint8_t* pNextInputBytes;
   pNextInputBytes = &pInputByte;`

In this example, we are taking the address of the array but it points to the whole array. i.e. If pInputByte[5] then &pInputByte will point the entire array of 5 elements. So when you try to increment it like (pNextInputBytes+1) then the address actually jumps by 5 addresses. This is useful in multi-dimensional arrays. Suppose double array[5][4] is a 2D array. Here, “array” is a pointer to array of 4 int but “&array” is pointer to array of 5 rows arrays of 4 int”